# Repopulating forms from window.localtion.search in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

ive got a problem which im not sure how to bite. 
Ive got a search form with a lots of filters. I store all current fitlers
in global namespage ie: window.NM.CurrentSearchParams = {} and i update the hash from filters. Each time the hash is updated, updating uri event is fired to
replate the window.localtion.search with current params. Everything is workin here fine. 
Now ive got a problem after entering page to deserialize window.location.search and 
update CurrentSearchParams with parameters. Thats fine also, but i would like 
to forms to repopulate based on those params. 
Ive got a little mess in code and not sure the best way to do it. 
How to bind form population in different views to the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

make the `CurrentSearchParams` a Backbone.Model so you can subscribe to `change` events on it.

```
NM.CurrentSearchParams = new Backbone.Model();


MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function(){
    NM.CurrentSearchParams.on("change", this.doStuff, this);
  },

  doStuff: function(){
    // do stuff here
  },

  close: function(){
    NM.CurrentSearchParams.off("change", this.doStuff, this);
  }

});
```

Note the "close" method that I added. This is very important and you need to call this when your view is done and ready to be closed, or you will end up with a lot of memory leaks and events triggering on zombie view instances: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/